# symfony2 include class pretty sql formatter and output sql to template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm looking to use the pretty sql formatter that is included as a library with symfony2.  To output some sql's on the template page.

formatter is included here
/vendor/jdorn/sql-formatter/lib/SqlFormatter.

I would pass it into the twig template

**PageController.php**

```
$queryBaseSQL = "SELECT * FROM exampleTable WHERE 'this' = 1 ";

return $this->render('sjQueryBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
  'queryBaseSQL' => $queryBaseSQL
));
```

I was hoping to be able to call it inside twig something like where

**(index.html.twig)**

```
{{ sqlFormatter::format(queryBaseSQL) }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$queryBaseSQL = "SELECT * FROM exampleTable WHERE 'this' = 1 ";

return $this->render('sjQueryBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
  'queryBaseSQL' => \SqlFormatter::format($queryBaseSQL);
));
```

Twig:

```
{{ queryBaseSQL|raw }}
```

Comment: This works, thanks - I will mark it as correct answer.  What does the "|raw" do?  why do you need to prefix the \ before SqlFormatter?

Comment: If you use SqlFormatter (not \SqlFormatter), it would search an SqlFormatter class into your namespace for the class (for ex. Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\SqlFormatter). |raw is that Twig doesn't escape your HTML in the variable.